# ElementType is invalid for ReactNative functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to export a ReactNative functional component and trying to use it in another file:

```
\\File : .\Pages\TestScreen.js
function  TestScreen() {
    return ( <Text>Home Screen</Text> );
};

export default TestScreen;
```

in another file i am trying to use it but its giving me error "ElementType is invalid : Expected a string or a class/function but got undefined.

```
\\File : .\App.js
import TestScreen from './Pages/TestScreen';
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return <TestScreen/>;
};
export default App;
```

I went through other answers and there the issue is about improper export [default vs named component]. but here i validated its fine as i am able to call the function if i change it to simple return a string.

Comment: How are you importing the `<Text>` component? is it a custom one or the one react native supplies? Do you have a `View` component anywhere?

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell for pointing it out, i was using Text from 'react' in TestScreen.js while Text from 'react-native' in App.js. 
update it to use react-native at both places and it worked.